# How to decode string from the pdf in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one pdf reader application for iphone.
In which I am searching text from the pdf.I have got proper text during searching.
But I have got some encoding string.How to do decode that string.

Please give me some advice.

Thanks

Comment: What about checking some implementation of open source pdf reader like xpdf or evince..they might have some nice ideas...

Comment: Ya I have check but there are same problem like encodding decoding

Comment: How are you doing it now? Some code and examples of the encoded string would help.